# Access new Config file created in custom classes in Laravel5

Tags: php, config, laravel-5

How can I access new config file(app_category.php) in Custom class??

Here is how I am trying to access config properties here. I want to create some functions related to config file.

```
<?php namespace App\Classes {
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

    class Common {

        public $category = \Config::get('app_category.categories');
        public function getAllCategories()
        {
            return $this->category;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $category
         */
        public function setCategory($category)
        {
            $this->category = $category;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have an expression (in this case it's a function call) as the default value of a member variable. Instead you should assign it in your *constructor*:

```
class Common {

    public $category;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->category = \Config::get('app_category.categories');
    }

// etc...
```

---

I personally prefer the `config()` helper function over the facade. I just wanted to let you know it existed in case you didn't already.

```
$this->category = config('app_category.categories');
```

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot. You saved my time :) One small change. It should be _construct() function.

Comment: I don't have 15 reputations as of now so can't upvote the answer. I'll do it once I have them. Thanks again !!